# TFS API with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, tfs

§I have been working with the TFS API that on the Microsoft website. According to the API documentation, [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) , I should be able to create a TFS workitem by sending a PATCH request with this type of request

```
https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemTypeName}?api-version={version}
```

and I make the `data` object in the AJAX request this:

```
[{
    "op": "add",
    "path": { string }
    "value": { string or int, depending on the field }
}]
```

However, when I create the PATCH request with AJAX using a IIS Express server, I get a `404 Not Found Error`.

I have no idea why this would be the case.

Comment: The path is most certainly incorrect...

Comment: But I am able to make get requests to the very same URL. Could you provide an example of a AJAX request to a TFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my example below, I've created a task work item named cecetest1 successfully with the following request:

```
var jsonObj = [{
                        "op": "add",
                        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
                        "value": "cecetest1"
              }];

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/TeamProjectCollection/TeamProject/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=1.0',
                        type: 'PATCH',
                        contentType: "application/json-patch+json",
                        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("domain\\username" + ":" + "password"));
                        },

                      })
```